# Azure DevOps Pipeline Build fails missing DLL reference in GAC

Tags: build, azure-devops, jenkins-pipeline, gac

We have upgraded our TFS server to Azure DevOps and I'm working on creating Pipeline builds for a solution that includes 3 projects, 2 of which compile to DLLs and one web service. Currently the build fails with this error:

```
> ##[error](XXX).sln\(XXXproject)\XXXpath\XXX.cs(8,30): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Common' does not exist in the namespace
> 'XXXX' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

That line references a DLL (compiled in another solution/project) that resides in the GAC so of course when it tries to build it doesn't find it.

I researched the error and one suggestion was to use the Download Build Artifact task to download the reference DLL from that other artifact prior to attempting to build the current solution...but I do not know what the Destination Directory should be for the Download Build Artifact task so that my current build will find it.

Or is there better way to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Which DLL is it? maybe you can use NuGet to download it.

Comment: Shayki, it is not a system DLL, it is a DLL produced by another one of our own projects...it has to be the latest version of that DLL ...so I would like to avoid having to package it up every time there's a change to it.

Comment: According to the error meeage, there's a custom DLL missing as you said, then use the Download Build Artifact should be the way to get the target DLL from a specific build. Is this build that generates target DLL different from the current one and the Download Build Artifact is not in your current build? If so, put the task in the current build so that the downloaded artifact could be found by the current build and you might need to publish build artifact task in the previous build. If i misunderstood anything, please feel free to tell.

Comment: Thanks Yang, I think you have a pretty good understanding of the situation...and you are correct that the DLL is from one build and it is referenced by a 2nd build which can't find it...the only thing I would add is that the 2nd build is looking for that DLL from the 1st build to be in the GAC...the first build has a gacutil.exe command in the post build to GAC the DLL but it is failing with this error: 

"Failure adding assembly to the cache: Administrator permissions are needed to use the selected options. Use an administrator command prompt to complete these tasks."

Comment: Sorry for long time no response because of my vacation. As you can see in the doc [Gacutil.exe (Global Assembly Cache Tool)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/gacutil-exe-gac-tool#remarks), administrator privileges is required which Azure Devops service can not provide. Is it possible you publish the dll generated from you first build and download it in the second and copy it(copy files task) to your web service reference folder where it stores all needed dlls?

Comment: Yang, so basically placing DLLs in the GAC is just not recommended or supported in Dev Ops ?  Is that correct? Because I've seen very little mention about handling GACked DLLs in Dev Ops other than the Pipeline - Builds where there are Tasks available that can run remote PowerShell scripts...but that places the "deployment" of files at the "Pipeline Build" stage rather than the "Pipeline Release" stage which I assume is not what is recommended?

Comment: According to the description of [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/gac), yes, it's not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because the referenced dll was over 100mb and I was using git lfs. In the classic pipeline editor, there is a checkbox to checkout git lfs files on the sources tab. For YAML, it is an option when pulling.